# couldnt find the path in merging pdf files in one single pdf document

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

im trying in c# to merge 2 pdf in a single one using the pdfsharp library, it shows an error that it couldnt find the path in the path where im going to save it, this is where i put my paths

```
 string directorio = @"C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\PDF\";//Directorio donde buscara los archivos pdf
                string destino = @"C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Prueba\";//Directorio donde estara el archivo unido
                string[] archivo = Directory.GetFiles(directorio);
                Unir(destino, archivo);
                if (MessageBox.Show("Espere un momento mientras su solicitud es procesada", "INFORMACION" + MessageBoxButtons.OK + MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Su documento se ha unido con exito, fue enviado a la direccion: " + destino);
                }
```

this is where my merge method

```
 private void Unir(string outfilePath , string[] pdfFiles){ 
       PdfDocument documento = new PdfDocument();
            foreach(string pdfFile in pdfFiles)
            {
                PdfDocument inputDocumento = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
                documento.Version = inputDocumento.Version;
                foreach(PdfPage page in inputDocumento.Pages)
                {
                    documento.AddPage(page);
                }
                documento.Options.CompressContentStreams = true;
                documento.Options.NoCompression = false;
                documento.Save(outfilePath);
            }
}
```

Comment: Does the folder **Prueba** exist under **C:\Users\Usuario\Documents**?  What happens when you press `WindowsKey`+`R`, type "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Prueba\" and click **OK**?

Comment: it exists it take to me to the folder "Prueba" its currently empty the folder

Comment: Can you confirm please which line it is?   Maybe it is the source file?

Comment: thanks for the support, i already finished, the error is that my version of the pdfsharp was an old one, only have to update it and it works ^^

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget you can answer your _own questions_ below.  This might help others in the future if they ever have similar problems.  This is how you get points! :)

Answer (score 0):

A file name is needed to save a PDF file, not a folder.

The `Save` should be made after the `foreach` loop to save only once.